# They type or namespace 'Assembly' counld not be found (Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am not sure how to get this reference to work for this portion of code. It is supposed to get access to the resource text that I have as an embedded resource.

```
Assembly assembly = GetType().GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
string resource = "Documents.Huckleberry.Txt";

using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resource))
{
     using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
     {
           bool gotTitle = false;
           string line;

           ...
     }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do exactly what the error message is telling you

Add

```
using System.Reflection;
```

You can work these things out by looking up the documentation

[Assembly Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Represents an assembly, which is a reusable, versionable, and
>   self-describing building block of a common language runtime
>   application.
>
> **Namespace: System.Reflection**
>
> Assembly:  mscorlib (in mscorlib.dll)

Comment: OMG thank you, I was so focused on the rest of my code that I forgot the simplest thing!